# UIPickerView not showing data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have three text fields in a view controller and those three textfields have 3 different `UIPickerView`s . Those three `UIPickerView`s are working fine .

But there is an error . **(E.g. - I have opened an `UIPickerView` and I tried to open other `UIPickerView` without selecting any value from the first `UIPickerView`, then it shows be a blank picker view.)**

How do I resolve this issue ..

This is my code for `UIPickerView`:

```
selectVistorPicker = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 270, 320, 255)];
selectVistorPicker.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
selectVistorPicker.hidden =YES;
selectVistorPicker.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:209.0/255.0 green:213.0/255.0 blue:219.0/255.0 alpha:1];
selectVistorPicker.delegate = self;
selectVistorPicker.dataSource = self;
```

Comment: Your data in not loading in the picker view here. Whenever you tap for second pickerview, dismiss the first one or reload the data for pickeview.

Comment: Can you tell me how to dismiss and reload the data of PickerView @ nilam

Comment: have you created 3 different objects for each pickeView?

Comment: You can check https://github.com/NilamMande/PickerViewModule code on GitHub, download and modify the code as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

try these i hope it helps..

if you use the same UIPickerView and pass the different value in UIPickerView then you have to reload it..

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [selectVistorPicker reloadAllComponents];
    return YES;
}
```